# LDAP Query to extract user with their complete Manager details

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, active-directory

Could you please guide me how to export user details from a certain group in AD along with organisation details (complete reporting hierarchy) to csv?

Example:

[image]

Regards
Aravind Viswanathan

Answer (score 0):

I played a bit and figured out this will work, if you need more help exporting let me know

```
    
Get-ADUser username -Properties Manager |foreach {
  $manager = $_.Manager 
 do
 {
  $manager = Get-ADUser -Identity $manager -Properties Manager -ErrorAction 
SilentlyContinue  

  $manager.name 
    $manager = $Manager.Manager
       
 pause
}
#do this until there is no more manager
until ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty(  $Manager))
}
```

Comment: I got an error when tried executing the above query "Get-ADUser : Missing an argument for parameter 'ErrorAction'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference' and try again." and "SilentlyContinue : The term 'SilentlyContinue' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of 
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

Comment: Also, please guide me where will i mention a Group so i get all the user details with their respective managers?